# NameError: name 'file' is not defined. while using tkinter Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button,filedialog,Text,END
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

window = Tk()

window.title("Paper Database")
def openpaperfile():
    global file
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    with open(filename ,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        file=f.readlines()
    Paper_message=Label(window,text='File uploaded')
    Paper_message.pack() 


def readFile():
    file_data=[]
    for i in file:
        file_data.append(file)
        sleep(1)
    

Paper_button=Button(window, text="Open Paper file", command=openpaperfile)
Paper_button.pack()

Read_button=Button(window, text="Read Paper file", command=Thread(target=readFile).start())
Read_button.pack()


window.geometry("720x480")
window.mainloop()
```

Error i got is `NameError: name 'file' is not defined`.
I just want to avoid my app from getting not responding. During the execution time, instead of using thread, we can display waiting, but the overall purpose is to prevent not responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `command=Thread(target=readFile).start` without the `()` near `start`. If you use `()` you are calling(invoking) the function, during code execution, while `file` is not defined and hence the error.

```
Read_button = Button(window, text="Read Paper file", command=Thread(target=readFile).start)
```

Though keep in mind, this will raise an error. If you click the button more than once. So to fix it, change the button command to:

```
Read_button=Button(window, text="Read Paper file", command=lambda: Thread(target=readFile).start())
```

However, here is an improved version of your function:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

.... #same codes
def readFile():
    try:
        file_data=[]
        for i in file:
            file_data.append(file)
            sleep(1)
    except NameError:
        messagebox.showerror('Choose file','Choose a file first')
```

Comment: You solution will raise exception if second file is selected and read button is clicked.

Comment: @acw1668 My answer was to the Q, I did not look for any other potential errors. Ive updated the answer now, though

Comment: You can simply use lambda: `command=lambda: Thread(target=readFile).start()`.  However you still need to check whether `file` is set inside `readFile()` in case `openpaperfile()` is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please also post the line on which the error occurred. I assume it's on this line:

```
    for i in file:
```

Indeed `file` is not defined in that scope, because you are missing a `global file` declaration an the top of that function.

Comment: Why would `global file` be needed on `readFile()`? It is already made available to global scope when declared at `openpaperfile()`

Comment: @CoolCloud This aspect of Python scoping is subtle: the scope of a variable is decided at parse time, not runtime, and it's decided based on where the variable is _assigned_, not _accessed_. The fact that `openpaperfile()` assigns to the global `file` is not known when parsing `readFile()`. It would work if there were also a `file = None` at the top level, because then `readFile()` would be able to find it in the outer scope. But even then `openpaperfile()` would still need `global file` because the _assignment_ to `file` would create a second `file` variable in the local scope instead.

Comment: Yes your right, but here the issue was that he was calling the function directly, then whats the purpose of a button?